# IONIC V1: Form Keydown Enter Fired on last field but not on the first field inside Device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Ionic app with a page with form with multiple fields. Except the last input field KeyPress Enter only moves the focus to the next field. I want the Enter Key to be fired when focus is on any field in the form.

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <form focus>
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="searchForm.name" name="fieldName" type="text" placeholder="Nome" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="70">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="searchForm.city" name="fieldEmail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" ng-maxlength="50">
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In the directives:

```
.directive('focus', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('keydown', function(e) {

              var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
              console.log(code);
              if (code === 13) {
              alert("enter pressed");
                //element.next()[0].focus();

              }
              e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

So, in the first field, when enter is pressed, the keydown enter(code = 13) is not fired, but on the second or the last field, keydown enter event is fired correctly.

How to fire event when user presses on Enter on the Device keyboard when focus is on any field on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing "focus" attribute in the form and put it in each input instead.

Like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="searchForm.name" name="fieldName" type="text" placeholder="Nome" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="70" focus>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="searchForm.city" name="fieldEmail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" ng-maxlength="50" focus>
        </label>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: nope still works the same way, moves cursor to next field and it fires when its on the second or the last field on the form.

Comment: Removing the form tag and attaching it to input manually works. Can you kindly update your solution to remove the form tags